# Java telnet login: stuck after sending user name

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to perform a programmatic telnet session in Java. I'm using `commons-net` `TelnetClient`, but I've also experimented with a direct socket. In either case I'm having the same problem.

I read up to "login :", then send the user name followed by CRLF. Then nothing, no other data is read, or written by server.

The telnet server is on an embedded device (a Star printer), so I'm wondering if there are some peculiar options required that I'm not setting, or that aren't supported by the `commons-net` `TelnetClient` class.

I can use Linux `telnet` without problems, and I can run my code against the telnet server in OSX and it works fine.

```
  TelnetClient client = new TelnetClient();
  client.registerNotifHandler(new TelnetNotificationHandler() {
    @Override
    public void receivedNegotiation(int negotiation_code, int option_code) {
      ALog.i(this, "negotiation code: %d, option code: %d", negotiation_code, option_code);
    }
  });
  try {
    client.addOptionHandler(new TerminalTypeOptionHandler("VT100", false, false, true, false));
    client.addOptionHandler(new SuppressGAOptionHandler(true, false, true, false));
    client.addOptionHandler(new EchoOptionHandler(true, true, true, true));
  } catch (InvalidTelnetOptionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/spy.out");
    client.registerSpyStream(fos);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  InputStream in = null;
  PrintWriter out = null;

  String ip = getIpAddress(p);
  ALog.i(this, "connecting to: %s", ip);
  try {
    client.connect(ip);
    in = client.getInputStream();
    out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    if (!expect(in, "login: ", 5000)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!send(out, "root")) {
      return;
    }
    if (!expect(in, "password: ", 5000)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!send(out, "password")) {
      return;
    }
```

Here's the `expect()` and `send()` methods,

```
  protected boolean expect(InputStream in, String s, long timeout) {
    ALog.i(this, "expecting: %s", s);

    final AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    final ExpectThread t = new ExpectThread(in, s, lock, timeout);
    t.start();
    synchronized (lock) {
      try {
        lock.wait(timeout);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
    t.interrupt();
    return lock.get();
  }

  protected boolean send(PrintWriter out, String s) {
    out.println(s);
    out.flush();
    ALog.i(this, "sent: %s", s);
    return true;
  }
```

And here's `ExpectThread`,

```
  private class ExpectThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream in;
    private final String expected;
    private final AtomicBoolean lock;
    private final long start;
    private final long timeout;

    ExpectThread(InputStream in, String expected, AtomicBoolean lock, long timeout) {
      this.in = in;
      this.expected = expected.toLowerCase();
      this.lock = lock;
      this.timeout = timeout;
      this.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int c;

      try {
        while (!isInterrupted() && System.currentTimeMillis() < start + timeout) {
          ALog.i(this, "starting read ...");
          while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            String s = new String(buffer, 0, c);
            b.append(s.toLowerCase());
            ALog.i(this, "read string: %s, buffer: %s", s, b.toString());
            if (b.toString().contains(expected)) {
              ALog.i(this, "found expected");
              lock.set(true);
              return;
            }
          }
          ALog.i(this, "waiting for read ...");
          SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        synchronized (lock) {
          lock.notifyAll();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

here's a wireshark pcap of the FAILED programmatic session,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iST80rpTN9c1RsRTNFaE5GZHM/view?usp=sharing

here's a pcap of a successful terminal (linux telnet client) session,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iST80rpTN9bDZFOHhkSHlPSE0/view?usp=sharing

I see the Linux client sends a "WILL AUTHENTICATE", where my code does not. I'd try it if I could figure out how to get `TelnetClient` to send such commands.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Trying not to make a mess of the post. I pasted the top level code. Note that I've tested this against a simple echo server I wrote and it works, so I believe there aren't any problems with the read / write code.

Comment: Check what the device is sending with a real Telnet client. Maybe for example there is no space after `password:`. NB you need to look up `Socket.setSoTimeout()`. You don't need all those threads and locks and waits.

Comment: Noted, however, that's not the problem. I can see through logging that nothing is read after I send the user name. Yes, I wanted to avoid getting to the level of `tcpdump`.

Comment: I would like to see a hex dump of a login/password exchange with the device using a real Telnet client.

Answer (score 3):

You must send the `\r\n` explicitly, not via `println()`. It must be exactly that, not whatever `println()` does on your system.

I also suspect your `expect()` method may be reading ahead. It should read a byte or a char at a time to ensure this can't happen. And please try it with a socket read timeout instead of that Megillah of threads and locks and waits:

```
protected boolean expect(Socket socket, InputStream in, String expected, long timeout) throws IOException {
    ALog.i(this, "expecting: %s", s);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    try
    {
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)
        {
            socket.setSoTimeout((int)(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()));
            ALog.i(this, "starting read ...");
            int c = in.read();
            if (c == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
              ALog.i(this, "read string: %s, buffer: %s", s, b.toString());
            b.append(Character.valueOf((char)c));
            if (b.toString().toLowerCase().contains(expected))
            {
                ALog.i(this, "found expected");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException exc)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

E&OE

Comment: I've tried that. It makes no difference, e.g., `out.print(s+"\r\n")`

Comment: Still the right way to do it though. Don't use a `PrintWriter`: they swallow exceptions. Use a `BufferedWriter.`

Comment: I've tried that too, just `OutputStream.write()`. Almost all the examples I can find online use `PrintWriter` so that's why I switched.

Comment: Poor stuff. You should never use a `PrintWriter` over a network.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using single-byte `read()`, no difference. I can't simply remove the `wait()`'s. See that the lock object is used to wait until the thread is done, and it doesn't simply do a read, it loops over the read until the passed timeout expires. So unless the SO timeout is a perfect factor of the total timeout, I still need to interrupt. Regardless, like I said, I've tested this against a simple echo server and it correctly reads and writes over multiple send / expects, so I don't suspect that code.

Comment: You seem to be more interested in defending your code than improving it, but I assure you you're mistaken. You can indeed remove the locks and waits and threads, and I will disprove your contention by counterexample presently. All you need is (1) `setSoTimeout()`, `catch (SocketTimeoutException ...)`, and (3) a little light arithmetic on time intervals. No thread, no lock, no wait, no interrupt.

Comment: no, i'm more focused on the problem on hand than optimizing the code friend. it's not wrong, you just don't like how it's written. i'm happy to look at your changes but that's not my problem right now.

Comment: try this.. its will work    `write(command); write("\r\n");`

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, it was an issue with the telnet negotiation with this particular server. I had to use a very specific echo option handler,

```
client.addOptionHandler(new EchoOptionHandler(false, false, false, true));
```

This means accept the DO ECHO that the server was sending. I discovered this discrepancy by comparing the telnet DO / WILL negotiation between the non-working and working sessions.